# meteor in PROD, deploying live code changes

Tags: meteor

What is best approach to have live code changes deployed to PROD. 
So that

1. i don't have to restart my servers.
2. And don't want to push the entire bundle.tgz file

What are the options ??

Answer (score 0):

We have a Meteor app in production - We upload the new bundle and prepare it (updating the native fibers) and restart - you have to restart the node thread.

You might say that you kick all clients, but Meteor is build to handle poor connections and will reconnect - it uses delay algorithm to help flatten out reconnects.

If the client is ready for migration the new code is then pushed.

*Our app is running Meteor inside cordova and we use appcache making sure that clients can allways open our app even if offline.*

NOTE: MDG is working on Galaxy - a cool and easy way of managing your own Meteor servers - so deployment would be a single line in a terminal. *(eta aprox. first part of 2014)*

Comment: >>Our app is running Meteor inside cordova and we use appcache making sure that clients can always open our app even if offline.           >> QUESTION : does this mean we first create a cordova project and use create a meteor project in that. Sorry i am new to cordova also .. do you follow any common steps/practices; common meteor package includes while creating similar projects. Also this project will also run on Web, little confused ?

Comment: Yes, it also runs from a normal browser. The cordova shell initialises plugins and uses initial offline fallback in case appcache fails. [video from community, similar approach](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eeY1mZhvDy4)

Comment: thanks ! any sample project with steps.. this one looks a little old.

Comment: Its a bit off topic, but: check out https://github.com/spacecapsule Theres different approaches in here, I've created runtime-cordova, meteor-cordova and packmeteor

Answer (score 0):

Easy deployment to your own server (DigitalOcean, Amazon EC2, etc) can be done using **[meteoric](https://github.com/julien-c/meteoric.sh)**.

**[Meteoric](https://github.com/julien-c/meteoric.sh)** can setup your server and deploy latest commit to production.
I use it and it works great.